# Disable keyboard on scrolling in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uikeyboard

A `UIScrollView` consists of various `UITextFields` like name, phone, etc. Of course, When i click on a textField, keyboard appears.

I want to know how to make the keyboard **disappear** once the user starts scrolling. Thanks for any Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` and once the user starts to scroll using `scrollViewDidScroll` method, you can make the keyboard go hidden. Try like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
 [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Make sure you set the delegate for your `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
         [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to hide keyboard.

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
      [self.view endEditing:YES];//hide keyboard
}
```